# Fullscreen toggle on Mac for Assassin's Creed Brotherhood?

Tags: macos, assassins-creed-brotherhood

I've tried everything: CMD+H, Alt tab, CMD+M, and nothing seems to be able to take me out of fullscreen mode for Assassin's Creed Brotherhood on my Macbook Pro. Are there any other ways so that it doesn't force itself into fullscreen when I launch it; maybe through a third party program?

Comment: Have you tried `Alt`+`Enter`?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: The "fullscreen/windowed" shortcuts I've found (with other programs) so far are:

`Cmd + Enter`
`Cmd + F`
`Ctrl + Cmd + F`


It is also apparently possible to set a "universal" shortcut for this using something like what [this answer/guide says][1], though I don't personally know if this works with AC: B.


  [1]: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230367 "Apple.StackExchange - Shortcut key for fullscreen mode"